# if $\lim a_n = \infty$ and $\lim b_n = B$, then $\lim (a_n+b_n) = \infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm having trouble starting the proof not sure exactly how to go about it. So far I know that for a sequence to go to infinity it means that for all $n >0$ there exists $n_0$ for all $n$ greater than or equal to $n_0, a_n >N$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M > 0$ be any known number, there exists $n_1 > 0$ such that $a_n > M - B + 1$ for $n > n_1$, and an $n_2 > 0$ such that $b_n > B - 1$ for $n > n_2$. Choose $N = n_1+n_2$ then if $n > N \to a_n +b_n > M-B+1+B-1 = M$, thus we arrived at the answer.

Comment: To be careful, you ought to add that $B-1<b_n<B+1$ for all $n>n_2$ and analogously for $a_n$ (albeit, I am being a bit nitpicky :) ). Otherwise, good setup!

Comment: @Clayton Why is that necessary? And in what sense is it analogously true for $a_n$?

Comment: @Théophile: I'm not sure if your comment was before the edit or not, but the issue has been corrected in the edit. +$1$ for the answer.

Comment: @Clayton: Ah, looking at the edit, I see what's going on. I was wondering specifically about $b_n < B+1$, because I think it's enough to have just $B-1 < b_n$, but you were emphasizing the condition $n > n_2$. And by "analogously for $a_n$", I thought you meant $a_n < \textrm{[some constant]}$, but again you were referring to the condition on $n$. Cheers.